# What is optimum or minimum data size required for training Word2Vec?

Tags: dataset, word2vec, sentence-similarity

I have a text dataset of 40 MB in size and I'd like to train Word2Vec to build a model that can be used to find similarities between sentences or paragraphs across documents that particular domain.
What should be the minimum size of dataset that Word2Vec requires for good results?

Comment: FYI: usually NLP people specify the size of their datasets in terms of the word or sentence count rather than in megabytes.

Comment: My dataset contains about 50,000 unique tokens. And about 2,00,000 words in total.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple CBOW model, the algorithm will observe all pairs of words let's call them (context,target), where target is a probable appearing word in +/- X words (window size = X) from the context. Then the neural net is trained to "given a context word predict a word close to it". So you should see how many unique words and pairs of words you have in your file. Judging by the size of the file you can't say, for example the Wikipedia dump for English is 15 GB.

Please check also some nice blogs to understand better the algorithms, a nice one is:
http://blog.aylien.com/overview-word-embeddings-history-word2vec-cbow-glove/

Good luck!